# RegExp is not a function

Tags: javascript, regex

its a search script im adding to my page. i found the script here:
http://www.javascriptsource.com/miscellaneous/search-the-page.html

i keep getting the error "reSearch is not a function"
ive spent an hour trying to learn about RegExp and [object HTMLBodyElement] but im getting lost!!

```
var searchElem = document.body;                   
var textNodes = findTypeNodes(searchElem,3);
var stringToSearch = textNodes[i].textContent;
var reSearch = new RegExp("a word",'gmi');

if(reSearch(stringToSearch)) { //error here "reSearch is not a function"
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: I guess javascript. If so, add tag please. Where is `reSearch()` function definition?

Comment: Seems to me, it should be `if(stringToSearch.match(reSearch)) { ..` or `if(reSearch.test(stringToSearch)) { ..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
// If you need the matches:
stringToSearch.match(reSearch);

// Or, if you just want to test for a match:
reSearch.test(stringToSearch);
```

---

`new RegExp()` will just create a [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) object which *is not a function*. It will have methods like [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test). Or it can be used in string methods like [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: No problem, trying to help.

Comment: Thanks folks, using reSearch.test(.. and its working as expected! im not sure why the original software was uploaded without that fix. now i just need to figure out how to modify it to highlight html items set to "display: none;" and a few other mods, im sure ill need more help soon!